# Change center and status of radius in random deformations of circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Thank you for your answer.
In the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-1.8,-1.8) rectangle (1.8,1.8);
 \draw[clip] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,45,...,315}] (\t:{1.5*(1+0.1*rnd)});
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {red,blue,green!70!black}
 {\draw[\X] plot[smooth,variable=\t,samples at={0,0.25,...,1.75}] 
 ({15+6*(rnd-0.5)+120*\Y}:\t);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

1. How to change the center and radius of the circle?
2. How to change the status of radius of the circle?
   [image]

Comment: The unperturbed radius is given by 1.5 in the above code, and the center is at (0,0). BTW, if the answer you are using here answers your earlier question, could you perhaps consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it? Also the center only has a meaning in relation to another coordinate. What precisely do you mean by changing the center?

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to make the parameters more obvious by constructing a `pic`. Consider for instance

```
\path (4,0) pic{random circle={radius=2,rays=4,offset angle=60,radius variation=0.2}};
```

Here `(4,0)` is the center, the radius is 2, there are four rays and a somewhat larger variation of the radius. The output is the right circle, with the left circle at `(0,0)` being kept for comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/random circle/.style={code={
 \tikzset{random circle/.cd,#1}
 \begin{scope}
  \draw[clip] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,45,...,315}] 
    (\t:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/radius}*(1+
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/radius variation}*(rnd-0.5))});
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\endrad}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/radius}*(1+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/radius variation})}  
  \foreach \Y  in {0,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/rays}-1}
   {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/colors}}[\Y]}
   \draw[\mycolor] plot[smooth,variable=\t,samples at={0,0.25,...,\endrad}] 
   ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/offset angle}+
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/angle variation}*(rnd-0.5)+\Y*360/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/rays}}:\t);
   }
 \end{scope}}},random circle/.cd,radius/.initial=1.5,radius variation/.initial=0.1,
 rays/.initial=3,offset angle/.initial=15,angle variation/.initial=6,
 colors/.initial={"red","blue","green!70!black","orange","purple","cyan"}]
 \path (0,0) pic{random circle} 
 (4,0) pic{random circle={radius=2,rays=4,offset angle=60,radius variation=0.2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are more parameters that you could vary such as the colors and the randomness of the rays, and one could make even more parameters pgf keys. Whether or not this makes sense depends on the ultimate purpose of all this.

Answer (score 0):

Following code draw a circle with center (0,0) and radius 1cm

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
\draw[draw=red,thick] (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw[draw=blue,thick] (0,0)--({cos(120)},{sin(120)});
\draw[draw=green,thick] (0,0)--({cos(240)},{sin(240)});
\fill (0,0) circle (1.3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-1.8,-1.8) rectangle (1.8,1.8);
 \draw[clip] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,45,...,315}] (\t:{1*(1+0.1*rnd)});
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {red,blue,green!70!black}
 {\draw[\X] plot[smooth,variable=\t,samples at={0,0.25,...,1.75}] 
 ({15+6*(rnd-0.5)+120*\Y}:\t);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

draw random deformations of circle with radius 1.
Now, I want ask some question. I would be appreciated if you could help me.

1. what change in the above second code (above code) can I draw a circle with center (-3,0)?
2. What is the purpose of the first line in the second code?

   \path[use as bounding box] (-1.8,-1.8) rectangle (1.8,1.8);
3. In tikz what is different between (x,x) and (\x:{\x}), for example
   (0,0) in the

   \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];

and (\t:{1*(1+0.1*rnd)}) in the

```
\draw[clip] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,45,...,315}] (\t:{1*(1+0.1*rnd)});
```